# vector<int> assigned by a function is not correctly deallocated

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to test counting sort on windows with qtcreator. I write a function for countsort which returns vector< int >. For the code below, after it is executed it will show

HEAP[labhw1.exe]:

```
Heap block at 0000000000995120 modified at 00000000009960D0 past requested size of fa0.
```

The debug shows ~vector went wrong. If I want to assign new value to B, it will also break. The operator= will invoke ~vector. It seems that B can not be correctly deallocated.

readtxt is a function that read integers from a txt file and return a vector. I think it's just a vector of int so there is nothing to do with pointers. Maybe this is caused by the life scope. Could anyone tell me why?

The debug shows :

```
1  ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey                                                        0x7ff9a61515f3 
2  ntdll!RtlZeroHeap                                                              0x7ff9a613f555 
3  ntdll!memset                                                                   0x7ff9a610e9af 
4  ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey                                                        0x7ff9a61504b1 
5  ntdll!RtlReAllocateHeap                                                        0x7ff9a605e57b 
6  ntdll!RtlFreeHeap                                                              0x7ff9a606061c 
7  msvcrt!free                                                                    0x7ff9a37298bc 
8  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate                  new_allocator.h 125 0x403990       
9  std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>::deallocate     alloc_traits.h  462 0x40442b       
10 std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int>>::_M_deallocate stl_vector.h    180 0x404252       
11 std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int>>::~_Vector_base stl_vector.h    162 0x4043c1       
12 std::vector<int>::~vector                                  stl_vector.h    435 0x404c11       
13 main                                                       main.cpp        19*  0x4020b4
```

*the line: vector< int > B

```
vector<int> countsort(vector<int> A){
  int k=0;
  for (auto a:A){
    if(a>k)k=a;
  }
  vector<int> C(k+1,0);
  for (int i=0;i<A.size();i++)C[A[i]]+=1;
  for (int i=1;i<k+1;i++)C[i]=C[i-1]+C[i];
  vector<int> B(A.size(),0);
  for(int j=A.size()-1;j>=0;j--){
    B[C[A[j]]]=A[j];
    C[A[j]]-=1;
  }
  return B;
}

int main(){
  vector<int> A=readtxt("A.txt");
  vector<int> B;
  B = countsort(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You should go step by step through your code with a debugger and double check whether you always access valid index of vector. You can also change usage of `[]` operator to `.at()` member function, it'll throw exception in case of using invalid indices.

Comment: are  you aware of what happen to vector B after the function countsort returns?????

Comment: Wouldn't the `C[A[j]]-=1;` bit cause problems if the same value appears more than once in the input?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I think I'm just playing with vector<int>. If the index is out of bound , the error will occur in the function but not when B is deallocated.

Comment: @user10395544 Wrong I'm afraid. If you have an index out of bounds then an error could occur at any later time (or could not occur at all). In fact during the freeing of memory is exactly the time when I'd expect to see an error.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I think B in the countsort function will deallocated but the value is already passed to B in main function.

Comment: Which` B` are we talking about? `B` in `main()` is never deallocated. `B` in `countsort()` *might* be deallocated, or compiler may do copy-ellision and no actual deallocation would take place.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I thought the correctness of algorithm may not influence this since I'm using vector<int> and the error occurs at deallocation. Now I feel I maybe wrong. I'll check it now.

Comment: @john Thanks. I'll check it later.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I mean B in countsort function may be deallocated after it returns and B in main is deallocated when main() return. If I want to assign a new value to B in main(), operator = will also invoke ~vector, and this error also occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hint, when you use vector and your program crashes call `at` method on vector instead of `[]` because `at` throws exception - it is helpful information. Your program crashes in this line

```
B[C[A[j]]]=A[j];
```

change it to

```
B.at( C[A[j]] ) = A[j];
```

and you will get exception - out of range. `B` vector is too small. Size of `B` should be

```
    max-value-of-C + 1
```

so construct B vector as follows

```
vector<int> B( *max_element(C.begin(),C.end()) + 1 ,0 );
```

now it works.

Comment: Thanks! I checked my code and this line should be B.at(C[A[j]]-1) = A[j].